# How to handle / make sure that Google Service Account connection is always stable

Tags: python, google-bigquery, service-accounts

I have a lot of python scripts which working with BigQuery, but sometimes have random issues (Connection Failed, Fail to Authenticate, Connection issue) and e.t.c...

This is how I'm using the service account:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/auth/Service_account.json'
```

**QUESTION:** What is the best way to make sure that if the connection failed on any point python will handle this and retry? / Make sure connection with Google Always Stable

Answer (score 1):

There are usually incident 3-4 times a year, when there is a disruption in service on GCP.

First to check is: https://status.cloud.google.com

If you encounter continues issues, than check your firewall, throttle settings or your current hosting provider's internet liability.

A service account is stable.

You should architect your application for retry by using Message Queues.

Comment: Thank you for the link! What will be the best way to handle connection issues caused by a service account?

Comment: I thought about different ways like checking the connection before execution each function and e.t.c... Because (Yes it's happens VERY rarely, but it does ) it faild execution on random stage.